# migrating to yarn 3 + workspaces + nohoist

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm migrating from `yarn 1.xx` to `yarn 3` and I'm currently having a workspaces definition with `nohoist` configuration in my `package.json`:

```json
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react-router-dom",
      "**/react-router"
    ]
  },
```

the new version of `yarn` does not support the [`nohoist`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/) feature the way it used to in previous version.
Yarn 3 has this [`nmHoistingLimits`](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#replace-nohoist-by-nmhoistinglimits) config which has only 3 options (`workspaces` , `dependencies`, `none`) - the only option to no-hoist a dependency inside a workspace (i.e. a package module in the monorepo) is to use the `workspaces` option but then each workspace (i.e. a package module) has its own `node_modules` folder, while their dependencies are hoisted to the root’s `node_modules`.
I ended up with a lot of common dependencies not hoisted up to the root. does anyone found a workaround for it? How can I get the following functionality, where I can no-hoist only certain dependencies?

Answer (score 14):

I’m wondering about the same thing. I think `nohoist` still works, though. It’s just deprecated.

Can you have nested `.yarnrc.yml` files to override the new setting per workspace?

Is there a way to define it per workspace somehow within `package.json`?

It does seem that the new options are much less granular than before.

In my case in only want it to apply to one package out of about 10.

UPDATE: I think I have a solution. You can indeed add a `.yarnrc.yml` file in the folder of a particular workspace that you do not want to hoist its dependencies.

It only needs to contain this single line:

```
nmHoistingLimits: workspaces
```

I confirmed this is respected by running `yarn config -v` in the root of my repo then again within the workspace. All other settings were inherited from the root `.yarnrc.yml` file, but the `nmHoistingLimits` setting changed from `none` to `workspaces`.

You still don't have the per-package granularity of before, which I think was intentional. However, allowing *most* workspaces to hoist their dependencies should hopefully provide some benefit.

UPDATE 2 - Something that works.

I've realized that `installConfig` is a section of `package.json`. Each workspace can define this section to override the default behaviour:

`<repo-root>/packages/my-package/package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "installConfig": {
    "hoistingLimits": "workspaces"
  }
  ...
}
```

I can confirm that after doing this and running `yarn` at the repo root, my offending child package kept its dependencies in its own `node_modules` folder.

Comment: The documentation for nmHoistingLimits in .yarnrc.yml (https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nmHoistingLimits) says,

"This setting can be overriden per-workspace through the installConfig.hoistingLimits field."

This sounds like the answer. I just don't know the syntax for how to do this. I think maybe there can be a section for workspaces in the root .yarnrc.yml file.